# Terratest throws error on assertions on errors

Tags: go, error-handling, terratest

Hello I have the following test

```
func badTags(t *testing.T){
  terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "../bad_values",
    }
  tags := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "test_required_tags")
  assert.Error(t, tags)

}
```

Note that the value of tag should throw an error but I keep getting the following error

```
string does not implement error (missing Error method)
```

If I remove the assertion , an error with a String message is throws as expected. How can I assert on the error?

Answer (score 0):

`assert.Error` [asserts that a function returned an error.](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Error), it's just like :

```golang
if err == nil {
    t.Error("no error returned")
}
```

But here the given parameter is `tags`, and `tags` is a string, according to the [terratest documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform#Output) that why your receive the following error :

```
string does not implement error (missing Error method)
```

Use `OutputForKeys` must solve your issue, please try this :

```golang
func badTags(t *testing.T){
  terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "../bad_values",
    }
  validTags := terraform.OutputForKeys(t, terraformOptions, []string{"test_required_tags"})
  assert.Contains(t, validTags, "test_required_tags")
}
```

Comment: That gives me an error about 'tags' value not being used

Comment: I added a print statement , just so the variable is used. But the test fails

Comment: Mmmh, ok I read the `OutputE` code and the function return an error only if it fail to read stdout for exemple but it didn't check the terraform success.

can you try this : 


`validTags := terraform.OutputForKeys(t, terraformOptions, []string{"test_required_tags"})`
`assert.Contains(t, validTags, "test_required_tags")`

Comment: I've edited my comment with this other solution for lisibility

Comment: I want to check for failure, I want to check that the output throws an error , how is that captured here? Can you explain? I want to assert that terraform.Output throws an error

Comment: Of course, `terraform.Output` didn't catch the `stdErr` and didn't parse the response. You have only 2 choices : compare the string to find part of the expected error or (the recommended way by terratest) use OutputForKeys and check if the tested field is in the result map (or if the value match with the given value for this field). https://godoc.org/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform#OutputForKeys